# SQL Server Primary Filename with different versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I'm working on a team project and many of us do not have the same version of SQL Server (one person is running SQL Server 2014 and another is running SQL Server 2012 Express). In the DB script, our paths for the primary and log filenames are different as we have different versions on SQL Server.

One primary is (SQL Server 2012):

```
(NAME = N'Database_Name', 
 FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Datebase_Name.mdf',
 SIZE =...)
```

While another may be (SQL Server 2014):

```
(NAME = N'Database_Name', 
 FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Datebase_Name.mdf', 
 SIZE = ...)
```

Is there a way to make the filename dynamic so it automatically recognizes the path it should go to based upon the version of SQL Server installed? Trying not to repeatedly change the filename depending on who has edited the script last.

Comment: A little more info is needed. Why are you running a database creation script? Why not just create it once and refer to the database logical name every time? Also there's no reason you can't just all create your database in C:\temp. It doesn't _have_ to go in that folder. You can use variables in various ways in scripts. You can use dynamic SQL or you can use SQLCMD mode variables. But I suspect you'r solving a problem that you don't need to have.

Comment: As others have indicated: It does really beg the question, why is the DataBase connection creation static script ? Most often the DataBase connection string comes from a configuration file which can be maintained independently  (does not compile)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for the recommendations on using the development environments. I understand this is best, but is not feasible in this situation. More research found an alternative solution for this case.

```
ALTER DATABASE [Datebase_Name] MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'Datebase_Name', SIZE = 5184KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Datebase_Name] MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'Datebase_Name_log', SIZE = 832KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: I'm curious how the above resolves the issue you raised.

Comment: Clearly it doesn't and has no bearing on data files

Comment: I removed the filename from the Primary and added this before the database is created. The alternative answers above did not work and repeatedly mentioned using a shared environment while the question did not ask how to do this in a shared environment. Regardless of the negative comments, the above code worked for the project across multiple devices using different versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to make the path of the data files dynamic.  This will only work if you use the default file location.  If someone decides to place the db files in a different location, this will not work.

```
declare @rc int, @dir nvarchar(4000) 

exec @rc = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
      N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
      N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
      N'SQLPath', 
      @dir output, 'no_output'
select @dir AS InstallationDirectory
```

The query returns the installation directory of your SQL Server instance.  The default location for the DB files is in the DATA folder in this directory.

**But I have to stress that it would probably be better to  work on a shared environment or at least get your environments in sync.**

Marius

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's feasible given your development environment and project development requirements, but in many cases a group of developers working on the same project:

- Have a consistent development environment for their project
- and/or Use a shared database for development